# How to display complete text when using bootstrap columns?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have bootstrap columns that has two labels and two inputs From and To, So From input is showing text correct but To input is not showing complete text when i load data dynamically.How can i fix this issue using bootstrap or I have to use css helper class to make it work.

when we use low resolution monitors problems occurs most of the time  e.g 1366 x 768

main.html

```
<div class="col-md-6 fieldHeight">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="issueFromDate" class="col-md-5">Issue Date
            Range:</label>
        <div class="col-md-7">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-5 changeWdh">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control"
                        ng-model="riskAssessmentDTO.issueFromDate"
                        name="issueFromDate" id="issueFromDate" disabled />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1">
                    <label class="control-label padd15"> To:</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-5 changeWdh">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control"
                        ng-model="riskAssessmentDTO.issueToDate" name="issueToDate"
                        id="issueToDate" disabled />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you read more into the bootstrap grid system. You could use a mix of the different `col-` classes in order to make sure everything fits on the screen depending on the resolution. See this example:
 [Zoom and unzoom to see the grid system in action](http://www.bootply.com/NyPmaTUj0X)

Also, a date field always contains a maximum amount of characters. Therefore, you could set a `min-width` to the input

Comment: what you mean by min-width to input i did not get this part can you please elaborate

Comment: Add the `min-width` CSS attribute to your input. That way, you'll make sure your input is always atleast the minimum width corresponding to your date. eg: `min-width:100px;`